# Why getElementsByClassName is not working while getElementById works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This first code is not working

```js
DN.onkeyup = DN.onkeypress = function(){
  var div = document.getElementById("DN").value
  document.document.getElementsByClassName("options-parameters-input").style.fontSize = div;
}
```

```css
#one{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    border:none;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div class="options-parameters-input">
    gfdgd
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table width="750" border="1" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><textarea id="DN"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gxTuG/85/

and this one works

```js
DN.onkeyup = DN.onkeypress = function(){
  var div = document.getElementById("DN").value
  document.getElementById("one").style.fontSize = div;
}
```

```css
#one{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    border:none;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">gfdgd</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table width="750" border="1" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><textarea id="DN"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gxTuG/86/

in first code i am trying to use `getElementsByClassName` and it does not work...

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined(…)

So my question is how to get working when I want to target element like div class ?

My goal is to make ability in options page panel that admin user can change / inject new css rules from textarea or input for certain elements. and there are elements like div class social-container-icons and other.

Also is this good way to inject new css rules ?

Thank you

Comment: bcz id is only on and class is one or more then one.

Comment: You did `document.document`. Also [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a DOM node.

Comment: It's actually not an array. It's an array-like object. It doesn't inherit any of the functions on `Array.prototype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Better use with `addEventListener()`.First declare with `DN` .then
>      call the value of the DN via `this.value`.Because Its same function
>      in the element.
> 2. And Catch the `ClassName` like 
>          `document.getElementsByClassName("options-parameters-input")[0]` End
>          with `[0]`.Class Match with multiple element .so identify with
>          [0].Match the first one
> 3. Dom of `fontSize` you should mention with `px`

```js
var DN = document.getElementById("DN");
DN.addEventListener("keyup",both);

function both(){
document.getElementsByClassName("options-parameters-input")[0].style.fontSize = this.value+'px';
}
```

```css
#one{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    border:none;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
<div class="options-parameters-input">
gfdgd
</div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table width="750" border="1" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><textarea id="DN"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you tell me also is this good way to inject new css rules for some elements ? or is there a better way ? thank you

Comment: Better way is Adding the class name with javascript [addClass](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp) for jquery . pure [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp)

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns array of object even though you have just one in your HTML. so you have ot use `getElementsByClassName("options-parameters-input")[0]` or whatever the index might be.

Comment: great ! it works now with getElementsByClassName("options-parameters-input")[0]

Comment: also please can you tell me is good way to inject new css rules ?

Comment: @Bundyboy Yes it is okay to do so, however if yo uare going to change more style attributes I would recommend adding a new CSS class -> this would save a lot of commands.

Comment: can you show me example of code please if you can. tnx

Comment: @Bundyboy [Here](http://codepen.io/tomasblazek/pen/vygZzK) is an example of when it is better to do it with the class instead of inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` always returns an iterable of elements which belong to this class. If you want to manipulate a certain object you need to provide an index of that element.
Method is called `getElement__s__ByClassName`. Keep that in mind.

for example:
HTML:

```
<div class="my-class>1st div</div>
<div class="my-class>2st div</div>
```

JS:

```
let myDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("my-class");
myDivs[0].style.fontSize = div;
```

Comment: It's `getElementById`, not as you suggest `getElementsById`. This would not even make any sense at all since `id` must be a unique **id**entifier (hence id) as per-document.

Comment: Okay, now you made things even worse `getElementsByIdClassName`. Check your edit.